# SwiftUI Expanding TextEditor

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I am a Flutter developer learning SwiftUI. I am working on a ChatGPT clone app in SwiftUI and trying to recreate the expanding `TextEditor`. I have tried many approaches mentioned in various articles, but all of them feel like a cheap workaround. The closest I have come is using a `TextField` with the following method:

```swift
TextField("What's up?", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
    .lineLimit(1...5)
```

However, I am unable to use the `Enter` button to create a new line in the `TextField`, which I believe is the reason `TextEditor` exists.

This is the view I am trying to recreate:

[image: ChatGPT iOS App's Expanding Text Editor]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop the "return" key from dismissing the keyboard by adding the [`submitScope`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/submitscope(_:)) modifier.

```
TextField("What's up?", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
    .submitScope()
    .lineLimit(1...5)
```

By default, tapping the "return" key creates a "submit" action and dismisses the keyboard, and you can handle this using `onSubmit { ... }`. If you add `.submitScope()`, there is no "submit" action, and so a new line is inserted.